# Best automatic file upload and metadata save flow

Tags: file-upload, upload

I am currently looking into file uploads and would like to operate the feature in a similar way to how YouTube, Facebook, Soundcloud etc. handle them. Files are uploaded in the background (showing a progress bar) while the user can enter any meta information and save that meta information during or after uploading. The file is only posted once the user hits a save button. Presumably, if the user cancels at any point during or after uploading has completed the saved meta information and file is deleted from the server/database.

What is the best flow for this? I have thought of a couple of options but maybe I am missing something.

1. Save metadata (without file) to the database and have a "saved" flag that will indicate if the file is visible in the user profile. Once file uploaded, save the path to the database. When the user "saves" simply set the saved flag to true.
2. Don't save metadata until file saved by the user. Upload the file and save the path in a temporary table. When the file is uploaded, enable the user to save the metadata at which point the file path will be moved from the temporary table into the usual table

Thanks!